# Getting ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 error while conencting toa MySQL db using Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to connect to a MySQL server via node.js but getting ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306.
I am running node from my windows 10 desktop and MySQL is running on a remote Linux server.I have admin access to MySQL but just cant reach to it via node.

My Code:

```
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
  hostname: "My mySQL server",
  port: 3306,
  user: "adminid",
  password: "adminpassword"
});



conn.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected");
  conn.end();
});


=================================
 if (err) throw err;
           ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue 
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument is `host` not `hostname`, and since you didn't specify a `host` argument it's defaulting to `'localhost'`.

Change your init:

```
let conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "My mySQL server",
  port: 3306,
  user: "adminid",
  password: "adminpassword"
});
```

Always double-check the documentation when you have issues like this.